# Listerner listening on wrong host (localhost)

Tags: oracle, localhost, listener

I created a listener (using netca) called listener.

When I start the listener (using lsnrctl start) I have the following log.

> ```
> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 24-JUN-2012 17:56:35
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting /opt/oracle/eesrv/11.2.0/db1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...
>
> TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
> System parameter file is /opt/oracle/network/listener.ora
> Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/sakura/listener/alert/log.xml
> Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
>
> Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sakura)(PORT=1521)))
> STATUS of the LISTENER
> ------------------------
> Alias                     LISTENER
> Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
> Start Date                24-JUN-2012 17:56:35
> Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 10 sec
> Trace Level               off
> Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
> SNMP                      OFF
> Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/network/listener.ora
> Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/sakura/listener/alert/log.xml
> Listening Endpoints Summary...
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
> The listener supports no services
> The command completed successfully
> ```

Q. Why is the listener listening on localhost and not on sakura ?!?

Here is my listener.ora file (where I clearly specify to use sakura):

> TRACE_DIRECTORY_PROD = /var/opt/oracle/otk/1.0/log/network/trace
>
> SUBSCRIBE_FOR_NODE_DOWN_EVENT_PROD = OFF
>
> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>       (DESCRIPTION =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sakura)(PORT = 1521))
>       )   )
>
> ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /opt/oracle
>
> LOG_DIRECTORY_PROD = /var/opt/oracle/otk/1.0/log/network

Why did I do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Does changing (HOST = sakura)(PORT = 1521) to (HOST = <IP of sakura>)(PORT = 1521) enable you to connect?

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct listener.ora file? t doesn't look like from looking at the value of the parameter log_directory_prod

Comment: @steve - the`*_PROD` parameters apply to a listener called `PROD`; the listener called `LISTENER` looks like it will get defaults for everything except the listen address. As the `lsnrctl` messages show both `localhost.localdomain` and `sakura`, I sspect `sakura` is just resolving to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`. Using an explicit external IP or FQDN may fix this.

Comment: Yes the problem was the /etc/hosts file. I was using an explicit external IP for sakura but I was also defining 127.0.0.1 as sakura to fix an issue with boot time for sendmail. Now it listening on the right server (ie: sakura) but boot time for sendmail and sm-client takes forever :( I can live with it thought ... Thanks for the solution !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Expanded from comment*

It appears that `sakura` is resolving to the same address as `localhost.localdomain`, i.e. `127.0.0.1`. This suggests that there is an entry in the `/etc/hosts` that is mapping `sakura` to `127.0.0.1`.

You can either:

- remove that mapping;
- change it to show an external IP address, if it doesn't resolve to one automatically;
- change your `listener.ora` to use a fully-qualified domain name if you have one that resolves to the external IP, e.g. `sakura.example.com`;
- or change your `listener.ora` to use the external IP address directly with no lookup.

The last option might be the simplest, unless you have a DHCP-assigned IP address; and os what @dseibert suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your hostname: {newHostName}

Step 1. Check environment vars:

```
> export ORACLE_HOSTNAME={newHostName}
> export ORACLE_UNQNAME=ORCL
> export ORACLE_BASE=/oracle
> export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.1.0/db_1
> export ORACLE_SID=ORCL
```

Step 2. Find in oracle installation dir (e.g. /oracle ) about "oldHostName" (e.g oracle_12C.localdomain)
to view your hostname:

> hostname
>   grep -r "oracle_12C" /oracle

In my case I found these files to change it manually "oracle_12C.localdomain" with new "newHostName":

```
File 1) /oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/install/chainedInstall/globalcontext.xml
File 2) /oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/inventory/Components21/oracle.rdbms.scheduler/12.2.0.1.0/context.xml
File 3) /oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/inventory/Components21/oracle.ldap.client/12.2.0.1.0/context.xml
File 4) /oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/inventory/Components21/oracle.server/12.2.0.1.0/context.xml
File 5) /oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/inventoy/Clone/clone.xml
```

Step 3. Start instance:
Go to sqlplus:

> cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
>   sqlplus / AS SYSDBA
>   SQL> STARTUP

Step 4. start listener {SID}
e.g.:

> cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
>   lsnrctl start ORCL

Step 5. Check result in console
...
Service "ORCL" has 1 instance(s).
...